# How to use the outset option from the inset command?

Tags: modeling

Inset, with the outset option : nothing is moving...

How to use it ? Or what is it supposed to do ?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The *Outset* option is when you want a new region of faces to appear *outside* the selection instead of *inside*. At first I start doing a normal inset on the face and then press <kbd>O</kbd> to toggle *Outset*:

[image]

You can see at first new faces are appearing inside until I press <kbd>O</kbd> and then new faces appear outside the selection.

Presumably, this simply doesn't work at the minute when there is no geometry outside the selection to *outset into*.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a demo:

[image]

Your problem is that your mesh doesn't have any faces around the one you are insetting. The outset mode moves the faces around whereas when it is off it shrinks the faces you are insetting.

Comment: Thanks... Ray was a bit faster (so I will validate his answer) but +1