# Outline face scaling

Tags: modeling

Is there any way to scale an individual face evenly shifting its edges in respective directions? Similar to Outline command in 3ds max?

UPD: I know that inset will work to make the face smaller, but what about the enlargement?
[image]

Comment: `Alt+S` will scale the selection along its normals, which in many cases will accomplish what you're looking for

Comment: In the single-face situation shrink/flatten won't do the trick. It will only move the whole face towards its normal direction :(

Comment: Ah, then you might be able to use inset faces with `I`, it'll create a duplicate of the edge loop but you can delete/dissolve it once you're done.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but, unfortunately, inset will work to make face smaller, and i am talking about enlargement. Will edit the question now.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61430 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184454